# httpClient.execute changes the host name passed

Tags: java, android

I have an android application that sends http request to a self-hosted API application running as a service.

I ran into a problem that the httpClient.execute(httpRequest) tries to resolve a different host name from what it has been passed, it actually removed part of the IP address in the url.
What I need to do to make sure my code resolves to the correct IP?

I tried adding 'no-cash' and 'no-store' to the request headers and I also cleared the application cash on the tablet and it still continues to happen.  I am using Samsung Tab 2 with 4.2.2 android version.

This is my code:

```
    try 
    {

        Log.i("RESTfulClientServiceResponse.Get", "url is: " + url);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        //httpRequest.setHeader("Cache-Control", " max-age=0, no-cache, no-store");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);


        stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line + newLine);
        }

        stream.close();

        return new RESTfulClientServiceResponse(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase(), buffer.toString());
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        if (ex.getMessage() != null)
        {
            Log.i("RESTfulClientService.GET method", ex.getMessage());
        }
        else
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RESTfulClientServiceException(String.format("Error getting from url %s", url), ex);
    }
```

The code errors out at line

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

and trows exception "Unable to resolve host.... ", but the host is different form what it has been passed. I stepped through the code and I can't find anywhere the wrong host that is trying to resolve.

This is the log from logcat:

```
I/RESTfulClientServiceResponse.Get(31355): url is: http://123.456.7.890:6005/dispatcher/statuscheck
D/libEGL(31355): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL(31355): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL(31355): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/OpenGLRenderer(31355): Enabling debug mode 0
D/ProgressBar(31355): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
D/ProgressBar(31355): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
D/ProgressBar(31355): updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
D/ProgressBar(31355): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
D/dalvikvm(31355): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
04-08 12:39:49.210: I/RESTfulClientService.GET method(31355): Unable to resolve host "123.456.890": No address associated with hostname
```

I replaced the real IP address in logcat log with bogus one 123.456.7.890, but what it is happening is dropping the 3rd part from it.

Comment: I don't get it. Did you change the URL to an incorrect IP? 123.456.7.890 will be treated as a domain-name, because it is a malformed IP.

Comment: No, the code calls the correct IP address. I just changed it in the LogCat text before posting the log. My link has IP in format xxx.xxx.x.xxx. What I get in the exception message is xxx.xxx.xxx. The '.x' has been dropped some how and I don't understand why and how.

Comment: But it is a valid IP? Not like the one from the example?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just didn't want to post my real IP.

Comment: The reason I ask is simple. If the "real" IP is in an invalid range, it may be treated as a Domain-Name In that case, there may be another problem with a domain name service. As far as I know a domain MUST have a minimum length of 2 lets say db.de and the lookup may drop a single number from the name. But if you are sure, that there is no type in the url, there i another problem. Can you reproduce the problem with an internal IP (Like 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x) ?

Comment: Yes, I can. The IP I am using actually starts with 192.168.x.xxx.

Comment: In this case you can post the concrete IP and URL, because 192.168.x.x is local ans will not be reachable from outside. Your example IP is misleading, because it is maformed.

Comment: The real URL is :http://192.168.2.196:6005/dispatcher/statuscheck

Comment: But it tried to resolve 192.168.196. It use to work before. I just ran into this issue as I am researching connection issue for client using the app.

Comment: Is your API hosted on the phone or somewhere on a server?

Comment: Is's hosted on a server and both the tablet and the server are connected to same WiFi network. But the API is not able to receive the message because the tablet app is sending it to wrong IP.  I looked into any possible piece of the httpRequest before is used in the execute statement, but everything is shows the correct IP.

Comment: Can you add this line?   

new URL(url).openConnection().connect();

This will make a GET request without any framework used. Maybe this method will throw a better Exception. (Or will work, in that case I would be completely confused)

Comment: Christian, thank you for all your effort and time to help me with this.  I couldn’t try your suggestion because cleaned up the app data this time instead of only the cache and this resolved my issue. I cannot reproduce the issue now, but I also can’t explain why it was happening either. I hate to use clearing up the app data as a solution, and I would like to know what cause the tablet to resolve to a wrong IP, so if it happens again I will try your suggestion.